# ZSync tutorial - Syncing CoreData data between devices

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios, synchronization, zsync

I am interested in syncing CoreData data amongst several apps running on iPhone, iPad and MacOSX.
I found ZSync project from Mr Zarra but did not find any related tutorial.
I contacted Mr Zarra who is always working on improving ZSync (thanks for that) and do not have planned yet to write a tutorial.

Any of you have implemented ZSync functionality into your apps and could provide a quick tutorial or a link to such tutorial?

Comment: Dang, Marcus is lazy. He probably spent labor day with his family instead of writing code for us. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this [video](http://vimeo.com/17089146)can be qualified as a proper tutorial but it should serve as pretty good introduction to ZSync.

From the description:

> In this session, Marcus discusses his
>   solution to local network data
>   synchronization using Core Data and
>   his new open source project ZSync. The
>   session walks through how the
>   synchronization of data works between
>   a Mac OS X desktop/laptop and a Cocoa
>   Touch device. This synchronization
>   works whether the associated desktop
>   application is running or not and has
>   the added bonus of being able to
>   synchronize with MobileMe if the end
>   user happens to have an account.This
>   video has been made available for FREE
>   to support the Open Source effort of
>   ZSync

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for a good link to this video!